# filesmatch htaccess convert to nginx (on plesk)

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

my old server had this in the htaccess file:

< FilesMatch "^resort$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
< /FilesMatch>

where I had a resort php file (without the php extension)...
so the file was domain.com/resort/param1/param2

I'm struggling to make the equivalent work for nginx...

i've tried these items, but none work:

location = /resort/ {

- ## try_files $uri /resort.php;
- ## try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
- ## try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
- ## try_files $uri $uri/ /resort.php$is_args$args;
- ## rewrite ^(.*)$ /resort.php last;

  }

So how do I execute the resort file as php, when this url is in the browser:
domain.com/resort/param1/param2.php

THANKS!

PS. would love some pages/resources/tutorials that explain "apache to nginx" for people who don't understand nginx :)

i've been to nginx site, but IMO, I need to know more than I do to figure it out or understand what the nginx site is saying.

update:
i think this is close, but still not working :(

this is url: domain.com/resort/city/state.php

here is directive:

```
location ~ /resort/ {
     rewrite ^/resort/(.*)/(.*) /resort/$1/$2 break;
}
```

Comment: FYI. I'm on a plesk server and I'm adding this to the "Additional nginx directives" section... so I'm thinking I only need to know/add the correct location part and the correct try_files/rewrite part.

Comment: there error I get:

17938#0: *92491 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/resort' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream

security.limit_extensions = FALSE

Answer (score 1):

this is what worked for me:

```
location ^~ /resort/ {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /resort.php; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute a file without a `.php` extension as though it was a PHP file, you will need to replicate the `location` block that handles those types of request.

It will look something like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass ...;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

To process the URI `/resort/param1/param2` using the PHP file located at `/resort`, you might use something like:

```
location ~ ^/resort/ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass ...;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/resort;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for `location` syntax.

Comment: Thanks Richard...

1) LOVE the link you gave :)
2) https://talk.plesk.com/threads/php7-and-php7-0-fpm-sock-how-to-make-it-work.339273/#post-807932   == that tells me I don't need to use the include or fastcgi lines????

i'm trying to get it to work :)